# 7 user LOGIN accounts to be directed in 7 different pages,what's wrong with this codes?

Tags: php, authentication

this is the codes I used in my login(logging.php) page..what should I do with this please?when tried to login the 1st account/other accounts..the login page is loaded but it does not redirect to any page instead, it only shows a blank page.. 
or if ever, my codes are wrong, can you please help me and provide a much better codes to replace this? any reply would be appreciated,thanks! :) I badly needed this for a project..

```
<?php

session_start();
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

if ( isset ($_POST['username']) )
{
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could'nt connect to db");
 mysql_select_db("tesda") or die ("cant connect");
 $sql=("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username'");
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if($result !=0 )
 {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $username = $row['username'];
        $password = $row['password'];
    }

if($row['name'] == $_POST['name'])
{

    if($_POST['username']=='tesda1'){
    header('Location: expi1.php');
    }
    else if($_POST['username']=='tesda2'){ 
    header('Location: expi2.php');
    }
    else if($_POST['username']=='tesda3'){ 
    header('Location: expi3.php');
    }
    else if($_POST['username']=='tesda4'){ 
    header('Location: expi4.php');
    }
    else if($_POST['username']=='tesda5'){ 
    header('Location: expi5.php');
    }
    else if($_POST['username']=='tesda6'){ 
    header('Location: expi6.php');
    }
    else if($_POST['username']=='tesda7'){ 
    header('Location: expi7.php');
    }
    else if($_SESSION['username']="$dbusername"){
    header('Location: attempt1.php');
    }
    else if($_SESSION['username']="$dbusername"){
    header('Location: attempt2.php');
    }
    else if($_SESSION['username']="$dbusername"){
    header('Location: attempt3.php');
    }
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you can use httpwatch to track the http communication to see what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if below code works out , I have made some minor changes...

```
 <?php

    session_start();
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ( isset ($_POST['username']) )
    {
     $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could'nt connect to db");
     mysql_select_db("tesda") or die ("cant connect");
     $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);


     if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
     {

        if($_POST['username']=='tesda1'){
        header('Location: expi1.php');
        }
        else if($_POST['username']=='tesda2'){ 
        header('Location: expi2.php');
        }
        else if($_POST['username']=='tesda3'){ 
        header('Location: expi3.php');
        }
        else if($_POST['username']=='tesda4'){ 
        header('Location: expi4.php');
        }
        else if($_POST['username']=='tesda5'){ 
        header('Location: expi5.php');
        }
        else if($_POST['username']=='tesda6'){ 
        header('Location: expi6.php');
        }
        else if($_POST['username']=='tesda7'){ 
        header('Location: expi7.php');
        }

    }else{
        header('Location:wrongattempt.php');
    }
    }

?>
```

Create a seprate file to handle unsuccessful attempts and show number of unsuccessfull attempts.

**wrongAttempt.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$attempt = ++$_SESSION['count'];
echo 'Number of unsuccessful attempts = '.$attempt;

echo '<a href="login.php">Try again</a>';


?>
```

In your login page add the below line at start. I am assuming your login page is login.php.
**login.php**

```
session start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['count']))
    $SESSION['count']=0; //initialize count session variable.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..it had directed to a page already but, I think my codes are wrong. you see,when I tried logging-in the username tesda1,eventhough the password is different it still directs to expi1.php when its supposed to go to either of the 3 attempts.php because the password is wrong..it only based on the usernames I have put and does not check the password anymore..what should I do?hope you'll reply again.. :)

Comment: Please check the updated sql query in code above . Your WHERE condition was missing password checking . Now combination of username AND password is matched . See if now it works out...

Comment: Its now being directed to its own page when the username and password is correct but when i tried a wrong password the attempts isn't being loaded.. it should show "incorrect password" or "incorrect username" but instead,it shows a blank page.. thanks for the earlier reply. :) What should I do with it?

Comment: Please,reply again ma'am/sir I still need some help.. I know i'll be getting it with your help, just a little bit more.. Please??? thank you! :)

Comment: If it worked , please mark it as correct answer by clicking on tick button